# My Indexeddb only creates the object store name but does not show the data i have added; how can i fix this?

Tags: html, indexeddb

So after the transaction is created, it is where it goes wrong as when I inspect the indexed db on mozzila firefox (it doesnt show at all on google chrome). It will only show the object store but not the data that was suppose to added ( John and Francis)      any advice would be great. thank you.

```
// This works on all devices/browsers, and uses IndexedDBShim as a final fallback 
 var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || 
window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

// Open (or create) the database
var open = indexedDB.open("jokes", 1);

 // Create the schema
 open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
var db = open.result;
var store = db.createObjectStore("MyObjectStore", {keyPath: "id"});
var index = store.createIndex("NameIndex", ["name.last", "name.first"]);
 }

open.onsuccess = function() {
// Start a new transaction
var db = open.result;
var tx = db.transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
var store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
var index = store.index("NameIndex");

// Add some data
store.put({id: 1, name: {first: "John", last: "Mercury"}, country: France});
store.put ({id: 2, name: {first: "Francis", last: "Perez"}, country: Spain});

// Query the data
var getJohn = store.get(1);
var getFrancis = index.get(["Perez", "Francis"]);

getJohn.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log(getJohn.result.name.first);  // => "John"
};

getFrancis.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log(getFrancis.result.name.first);   // => "Francis"
};

// Close the db when the transaction is done
tx.oncomplete = function() {
    db.close();
};
  }
```

Comment: the semi colon missing after the "create  the schema " code is not the issue btw i just tried to remove it to see if it would work however it was not the case

Answer (score 0):

here are some issue that i could find. Fixing them fixed the issue.

1. In the lines where you are putting data into the Indexed DB, you gotta use quotes for country name.

   store.put({id: 1, name: {first: "John", last: "Mercury"}, country: **"France"**});
2. Secondly, all IndexedDB operations are async, so you gotta wait for success of the put operation before you can fetch.

`let putOp = store.put({id: 1, name: {first: "John", last: "Mercury"}, country: 'France'});
putOp.onsuccess = function() { // Fetch records here }`

Comment: The speech marks make sense thank you for that however i am still puzzled with the second solution here is what i typed not sure if it is incorrect
       let putOp = store.put({id: 1, name: {first: "John", last: "Mercury"}, country: 
      "France"});
     let putOp = store.put ({id: 2, name: {first: "Francis", last: "Perez"}, country: 
     "Spain"});
        putOp.onsuccess = function(event) { db = request.result;
      console.log("success: "+ open); } ;

Comment: db = open.result*

Comment: You gotta query the store for the record that was just inserted in the onsuccess handler.

Comment: See, what you should do is  create an interface for interacting with the indexed DB. It should have 3 methods - for querying, adding and deleting. These methods should either call the  callback(with err or response) or return a promise(resolve or reject based on success of error of operation). If you don't want to write your own layer, you can always use libraries like dexie or lovefield.